# Pandas development environment: pytest does not see changes after building edited .pyx file

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pytest, cython

**Q:** Why is pytest not seeing changes when I edit a `.pyx` file and build? What step am I missing?

I'm using Visuals Studio Code with remote containers as described at the [end of this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing_environment.html#option-2-creating-an-environment-using-docker).

If I add changes to [pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9e6bbdebb6f4f4f8da6e635508a15276bea5792e/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L300), and then run

```
(pandas-dev) root@60017c489843:/workspaces/pandas# python setup.py build_ext -j 4
Compiling pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx
/opt/conda/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:108: _BetaConfiguration: Support for `[tool.setuptools]` in `pyproject.toml` is still *beta*. warnings.warn(msg, _BetaConfiguration)
# ... more output here without errors ...
```

my [unit-test](https://github.com/markopacak/pandas/blob/65cd5da8ddaa56e2fe5c53e9379a442ede27fa4f/pandas/tests/tseries/offsets/test_offsets.py#L742-L748) fails because it does not test against my updated version of `offsets.pxy`. He points to a line (see below) where the error exists only in the old version of the file.

```
pandas/tests/tseries/offsets/test_offsets.py ........x......................................................F

.... more output here ...
E   TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'milliseconds'
pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx:325: TypeError
```

Whatever change I add to `cdef _determine_offset` and build, pytest does not see the edits, therefore I assume I'm missing a compilation step somewhere.

#### Reproducible example

1. clone my pandas fork: `git clone git@github.com:markopacak/pandas.git`
2. `git checkout bug-dateoffset-milliseconds`
3. In your dev-environment (docker container or VS Code remote container) run:

   - `conda activate pandas-dev`
   - `python setup.py build_ext -j 4`
   - `pytest pandas/tests/tseries/offsets/test_offsets.py::TestDateOffset`

*Assumes you have set-up a dev environment for pandas, ideally using remote-containers on VS Code like I did.*

---

```
(pandas-dev) root@60017c489843:/workspaces/pandas# python --version
Python 3.8.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to install once the extensions are built (otherwise where are the built extension and how python/pytest should know where to look?). This is how my workflow looked some time ago (not sure it still applies but should be close enough):

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace -j 4
python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517

...

pytest pandas/tests/xxxx/yyyy.py
```

Installing in development mode (`-e`) is the most convenient option in my opinion for development.

Comment: Thx, adding the `--inplace` option did it for me. No need for `python -m pip install -e ...`. Probably it's only need if you are developing outside a container